# Access object by name in array list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object that contains an array list of objects. I'd like to get the value of an object within the array list.

example

```
var data = { 
             items1: [{ id: 1, name: 'foo' }, { id: 2, name: 'bar' }], 
             items2: [{ id: 3, name: 'foo' }, { id: 4, name: 'bar' }] 
           };
```

I'm trying to access the name of id:1 in array list items1.

I thought it would be something like

```
data['items1']['id'].name
```

but I think I'm missing something. Anybody know what I might be doing wrong

Comment: For starters, that appears to be invalid json, given you don't have a comma after the first item.

Comment: Feel free to correct the issue you see, I just quickly modified the post from another example on the web to try and demonstrate what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Not going to.  One never modifies the code in the OP's question, as that changes the meaning.  If the code is faulty, or they misposted, it is their job to fix/correct it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an object with 2 keys (`items1` and `items2`), both of which are *arrays*. Within each array are elements which are objects, each containing 2 keys (`id` and `name`).

To get the `id` of the first element of the `items1` array you would do:

```
data.items1[0].id
```

which would return `1`.

If you wanted to search for the object with a name of 'bar' in `items2` you could do something like:

```
function find(item, name) {
    //no such array
    if(!data[item])
        return;

    //search array for key
    var items = data[item];
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        //if the name is what we are looking for return it
        if(items[i].name === name)
            return items[i];
    }
}

var obj = find('items2', 'bar');
obj.id; //4
obj.name; //'bar'
```

I highly suggest reading about [JavaScript Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) and [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: In kelsadita's example, he shows me being able to use ['items1'], something I'm going to dynamically pass in, is that okay to do?

Comment: You may want to read up on [javascript objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) to learn how keys work. Doing `data.items2` is just sugar for `data['items2']`, and something like `var k = 'items2'; data[k];` is the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

You can only access array items by their numeric index. For example:

```
// The first item in the array
data['items1'][0].name
// The second
data['items1'][1].name
```

If you want to lookup by id, you can make a little function to do that for you:

```
function getItemById(anArray, id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < anArray.length; i += 1) {
        if (anArray[i].id === id) {
            return anArray[i];
        }
    }
}

var theName = getItemById(data['items1'], 1).name;
```

Answer (score 2):

As items1 is array, you should write:

```
data.items1[0].name
```

Comment: I'm going to dynamically pass in the array needed, so this wouldn't work for me.

Comment: @George Then you need to either restructure your json or create a function to find adjacent values.  The first one is the easier method.

Comment: @Daedalus do you have a better idea how to restructure my json?

Comment: Very simple. Put "id" as a key. Then you will be able to access data directly. E.g. data.items1.id1.name

Answer (score 1):

Try this `data['items1'][0].name`

Comment: Wouldn't do it, per the structure of the json.

Comment: What does the zero stand for?

Comment: @George: its for the first element in items1 array